# How to identify the element using xpath and text

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

In below snippet , how do i select the label using the text "No gateway"? I can use ID , but wanted to select by text.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group" style="">
                    <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12" for="noGateway" style="background: rgb(204, 136, 136); border: 2px solid red;">
                        <input type="radio" data-ng-model="proxyType" value="noGateway" name="noGateway" id="noGateway" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" style="">
                        No gateway
                    </label>
                </div>
```

Comment: <div class="form-group" style="">
     <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12" for="noGateway" style="background: rgb(204, 136, 136); border: 2px solid red;">
      <input type="radio" data-ng-model="proxyType" value="noGateway" name="noGateway" id="noGateway" class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" style="">
      No gateway
     </label>
    </div>

Comment: If you have `id`, use `id`.

Comment: why do you want to select a label ? you may want to click on input ?

Answer (score 1):

To identify the label using the text **No gateway** you can use either of the following *Java* solutions:

- *XPath* with contains():

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(.,'No gateway')]"));
  ```
- *XPath* with normalize-space():

  ```
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[normalize-space()='No gateway']"));
  ```

Comment: Thanks it helped , any article that explains A-Z about xpath?

Comment: @karthikloganathan Checkout [XPath Tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp). Let me know if you need more references.